# Ordering a list of objects by the Year element of a DateTimeField

Tags: python, django

I have the following model defined in models.py

```
class Schoolclass(models.Model):
    ...
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('date created')
```

In my views.py I want to order the list of Schoolclass objects **by the year only** associated with date_created. I specifically don't want ordering to take account of any other element of the DateTimeField. The reason being that I wish secondary ordering to occur through a different field.

This is what I can come up with but it doesn't work.

```
def index(request):
    class_list = SchoolClass.objects.order_by('date_created__year')
```

In case it helps I get the following error when I run the above code:

```
Join on field 'date_created' not permitted. Did you misspell 'year' for the lookup type?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `year` field only exists in Python, not in the database. I guess you'll have to use `extra()` and make it explicit to the database that it should order by the year part of the datetime field. How exactly to do that will depend on your database.

This should work for MySQL:

```
def index(request):
    class_list = SchoolClass.objects.extra(select={'year_created': 'YEAR(date_created)'}, 
                                           order_by=['year_created'])
```

If you're using other database, you'll have to replace `YEAR(date_created)` with the equivalent operation to extract the year from a datetime field.